# Reference a previous value at runtime in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` as follows

```
library(data.table)
data = structure(list(value = c(54.71, 62.48, 57.88, 60.64, 56, 54.28, 
55.22, 63.77, 64.47, 67.36, 64.45, 64.7, 65.15, 62.19, 70.25, 
75.47, 79.75, 75.75, 75.24, 76, 80.25, 91.04, 95.13, 102.18, 
92.28, 87.24, 82.32, 89.73, 77.01, 73.06, 74.51, 68.52, 65.64, 
66.65, 60.36, 57.58, 54.92, 51.16, 46.87, 53.24, 52.99, 59.24, 
58, 62.93, 60.05, 60.79, 115.09, 125.28, 164.87, 118.48, 112.28, 
123.73, 142.95, 134.49, 129.28, 128.86, 144.28, 140.52, 144.3, 
126.07, 123.33, 127.29, 112.46, 110.46, 104.51, 110.4, 104.65, 
97.55, 91.79, 100.61, 101.44, 107.38, 111.24, 116.33, 113.75, 
108.56, 109.02, 114.2, 107.36, 98.19), upper = c(76.31, 82.9, 
88.17, 88.44, 83.69, 82.03, 77.87, 84.06, 85.11, 92.01, 88.91, 
88.86, 88.65, 86.81, 89.81, 99.53, 102.75, 100.9, 99.56, 97.89, 
100.81, 108.36, 116.05, 117.58, 116.51, 106.83, 100.9, 108.91, 
105.27, 93.69, 103.98, 100.61, 95.15, 96.8, 90.28, 86.06, 81.53, 
77.23, 76.3, 79.68, 81.95, 82.72, 81.05, 84.32, 84.93, 82.54, 
127.88, 150.07, 186.47, 192.06, 176.37, 174.29, 190.06, 204.7, 
188.58, 188.46, 195.84, 202.25, 194.74, 185.08, 175.34, 176.93, 
170.44, 157.73, 157.63, 157.99, 151.59, 141.08, 131.59, 130.42, 
138.15, 140.31, 143.42, 150.07, 147.75, 142.11, 140.09, 144.33, 
141.45, 133.73), lower = c(30.22, 36.13, 39.01, 38.48, 34.51, 
32.6, 31.6, 36.28, 38.3, 44.67, 43.08, 39.94, 42.28, 40.71, 42.94, 
51.51, 55.67, 54.38, 54.23, 54.55, 57.46, 61.74, 71.63, 77.6, 
80.54, 69.57, 62.12, 67.59, 59.28, 42.7, 51.32, 45.09, 40.08, 
42.53, 35.77, 32.55, 27.1, 20.57, 21.06, 24.82, 28.72, 30.88, 
30.95, 35.52, 36.42, 34.22, 70.75, 85.33, 103.24, 87.58, 67.9, 
62.02, 73.05, 84.76, 71.63, 77.33, 84.64, 90.02, 89.1, 77.7, 
72.82, 75.07, 68.71, 59.23, 62.23, 64.66, 62.64, 60.89, 55.12, 
61.59, 71.59, 74.1, 79.39, 85.32, 83.95, 76.89, 76.09, 79.39, 
74.65, 73.61), xyz_expected = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

> data

      value  upper  lower xyz_expected
 1:  54.71  76.31  30.22         TRUE
 2:  62.48  82.90  36.13         TRUE
 3:  57.88  88.17  39.01         TRUE
 4:  60.64  88.44  38.48         TRUE
 5:  56.00  83.69  34.51         TRUE
 6:  54.28  82.03  32.60         TRUE
 7:  55.22  77.87  31.60         TRUE
 8:  63.77  84.06  36.28         TRUE
 9:  64.47  85.11  38.30         TRUE
10:  67.36  92.01  44.67         TRUE
11:  64.45  88.91  43.08         TRUE
12:  64.70  88.86  39.94         TRUE
13:  65.15  88.65  42.28         TRUE
14:  62.19  86.81  40.71         TRUE
15:  70.25  89.81  42.94         TRUE
16:  75.47  99.53  51.51         TRUE
17:  79.75 102.75  55.67         TRUE
18:  75.75 100.90  54.38         TRUE
19:  75.24  99.56  54.23         TRUE
20:  76.00  97.89  54.55         TRUE
21:  80.25 100.81  57.46         TRUE
22:  91.04 108.36  61.74         TRUE
23:  95.13 116.05  71.63         TRUE
24: 102.18 117.58  77.60         TRUE
25:  92.28 116.51  80.54         TRUE
26:  87.24 106.83  69.57         TRUE
27:  82.32 100.90  62.12         TRUE
28:  89.73 108.91  67.59         TRUE
29:  77.01 105.27  59.28        FALSE
30:  73.06  93.69  42.70        FALSE
31:  74.51 103.98  51.32        FALSE
32:  68.52 100.61  45.09        FALSE
33:  65.64  95.15  40.08        FALSE
34:  66.65  96.80  42.53        FALSE
35:  60.36  90.28  35.77        FALSE
36:  57.58  86.06  32.55        FALSE
37:  54.92  81.53  27.10        FALSE
38:  51.16  77.23  20.57        FALSE
39:  46.87  76.30  21.06        FALSE
40:  53.24  79.68  24.82        FALSE
41:  52.99  81.95  28.72        FALSE
42:  59.24  82.72  30.88        FALSE
43:  58.00  81.05  30.95        FALSE
44:  62.93  84.32  35.52        FALSE
45:  60.05  84.93  36.42        FALSE
46:  60.79  82.54  34.22        FALSE
47: 115.09 127.88  70.75         TRUE
48: 125.28 150.07  85.33         TRUE
49: 164.87 186.47 103.24         TRUE
50: 118.48 192.06  87.58         TRUE
51: 112.28 176.37  67.90         TRUE
52: 123.73 174.29  62.02         TRUE
53: 142.95 190.06  73.05         TRUE
54: 134.49 204.70  84.76         TRUE
55: 129.28 188.58  71.63         TRUE
56: 128.86 188.46  77.33         TRUE
57: 144.28 195.84  84.64         TRUE
58: 140.52 202.25  90.02         TRUE
59: 144.30 194.74  89.10         TRUE
60: 126.07 185.08  77.70         TRUE
61: 123.33 175.34  72.82         TRUE
62: 127.29 176.93  75.07         TRUE
63: 112.46 170.44  68.71         TRUE
64: 110.46 157.73  59.23         TRUE
65: 104.51 157.63  62.23         TRUE
66: 110.40 157.99  64.66         TRUE
67: 104.65 151.59  62.64         TRUE
68:  97.55 141.08  60.89        FALSE
69:  91.79 131.59  55.12        FALSE
70: 100.61 130.42  61.59        FALSE
71: 101.44 138.15  71.59        FALSE
72: 107.38 140.31  74.10        FALSE
73: 111.24 143.42  79.39        FALSE
74: 116.33 150.07  85.32        FALSE
75: 113.75 147.75  83.95        FALSE
76: 108.56 142.11  76.89        FALSE
77: 109.02 140.09  76.09        FALSE
78: 114.20 144.33  79.39        FALSE
79: 107.36 141.45  74.65        FALSE
80:  98.19 133.73  73.61        FALSE
     value  upper  lower xyz_expected
```

I want to calculate the new value of `xyz` based on the `fcase statement` given in code below. The same can be done in a lengthy `for` loop but I just want to use `data.table`.

```
data[, xyz := TRUE]
data[, xyz := {
  fcase(
    value > upper, TRUE,
    value < lower, FALSE,
    data.table::between(value, lower = lower, upper = upper), 
    {
      shift(xyz, 1, type = "lag")
      if(xyz == TRUE & lower < shift(lower, 1, type = "lag"))
      {
        lower = shift(lower, 1, type = "lag")
      } 
      if(xyz == FALSE & upper > shift(upper, 1, type = "lag"))
      {
        upper = shift(upper, 1, type = "lag")
      } 
    }
  )
}]
```

Running the above code gives me the following error -

```
Error in `:=`(xyz, { : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

I will appreciate it if someone can show me how to resolve this error, or is there no way to accomplish this task using `data.table`?

**Update - 1**
Following code works, but it creates a local copy of variable `lower` in the last `fcase` condition and the value of `lower` is not updated in the original data.table `data` during runtime.

```
data[, xyz := TRUE]
data[, xyz := {
  fcase(
    value > upper, TRUE,
    value < lower, FALSE,
    data.table::between(value, lower = lower, upper = upper), 
    {
      lower = ifelse(xyz == TRUE & lower < shift(lower, 1, type = "lag"), shift(lower, 1, type = "lag"), lower)
      upper = ifelse(xyz == FALSE & upper > shift(upper, 1, type = "lag"), shift(upper, 1, type = "lag"), upper)
      shift(xyz, 1, type = "lag")
    }
  )
}]
```

**Update - 2**
As suggested by @r2avens I have tried using the function `Reduce`. I have no idea how to use the function `Reduce` in this scenario. I will appreciate if someone can show me the correct way to use `Reduce`.

```
  temp_dt[, xyz := TRUE]
  temp_dt[, xyz := {
    Reduce(fcase(
      value > upper, TRUE,
      value < lower, FALSE,
      data.table::between(value, lower = lower, upper = upper), 
      {
        lower = ifelse(xyz == TRUE & lower < shift(lower, 1, type = "lag"), shift(lower, 1, type = "lag"), lower)
        upper = ifelse(xyz == FALSE & upper > shift(upper, 1, type = "lag"), shift(upper, 1, type = "lag"), upper)
        shift(xyz, 1, type = "lag")
      }
    ), accumulate = TRUE)
  }]
```

```
Error in Reduce(fcase(value > upper, TRUE, value < lower, FALSE, data.table::between(value, :
argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

**Update - 3**
Following is the working `for` loop -

```
calculate  <- function(x){
  for (current in 2:nrow(x)) {
    previous <- current - 1
    
    nxt <- ifelse(
      current == nrow(x),
      NA,
      current + 1
    )
    
    if (isTRUE(as.numeric(x$value[current]) > as.numeric(x$upper[previous]))) {
      x$xyz[current] <- TRUE
    } else if (isTRUE(as.numeric(x$value[current]) < as.numeric(x$lower[previous]))) {
      x$xyz[current] <- FALSE
    } else {
      x$xyz[current] <- x$xyz[previous]

      if (isTRUE(as.logical(x$xyz[current] == TRUE)) & isTRUE((as.numeric(x$lower[current]) < as.numeric(x$lower[previous])))) {
        x$lower[current] <- x$lower[previous]
      }
      
      if (isTRUE(as.logical(x$xyz[current] == FALSE)) & isTRUE((as.numeric(x$upper[current]) > as.numeric(x$upper[previous])))) {
        x$upper[current] <- x$upper[previous]
      }
    }
    
  }
  return(x)
}


dt1 = calculate(data)
```

**Benchmarking** - While benchmarking, statements of `data.table` solution do not completely match the statements in `forloop` solution since the exact solution using `data.table` is yet to be found. But it gives a very close approximation.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
forloop = calculate(data),
MrSmith = MrSmith(data, nrow(data)),
Alexis_cpp = Alexis_cpp(data),
datatable = {data[, xyz := TRUE]
data[, xyz := {
  fcase(
    value > upper, TRUE,
    value < lower, FALSE,
    data.table::between(value, lower = lower, upper = upper), 
    {
      lower = ifelse(xyz == TRUE & lower < shift(lower, 1, type = "lag"), shift(lower, 1, type = "lag"), lower)
      upper = ifelse(xyz == FALSE & upper > shift(upper, 1, type = "lag"), shift(upper, 1, type = "lag"), upper)
      shift(xyz, 1, type = "lag")
    }
  )
}]}
, times = 10)

Unit: microseconds
       expr        min         lq        mean      median         uq        max neval cld
    forloop  10718.595  10774.386  10953.7406  10846.0465  11120.934  11325.962    10  b 
    MrSmith 278600.405 280761.948 296481.4276 298688.6040 305259.497 331570.519    10   c
 Alexis_cpp     13.288     13.924     25.4258     27.9855     32.196     45.881    10 a  
  datatable   1656.803   1700.195   1826.1999   1764.6285   1938.074   2125.853    10 ab
```

Comment: `lower` is a double and `fcase` assigns it to `xyz`value. What is `xyz` type supposed to be? I understood `logical`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @Waldi. I have updated the code so that new value of ```lower``` goes back to ```lower``` only. Yes, ```xyz``` is logical. Since the value of ```lower``` changed at runtime, this new value will be used in calculating the new value of ```xyz```. It is easy to visualize in terms of ```for``` loop, but I am not sure, how to do this task in ```fcase``` statements such as above in ```data.table```.

Comment: FYI, we can use data.table::between, to check if value is between 2 values.

Comment: I cannot replicate your error, i get a different one. Could you elaborate how you load the `data.table` package? I know the same error happened to me once when i did not load data.table as a whole via `library(data.table)`

Comment: You're going to need something like `Reduce(.., accumulate=TRUE)` since your value of `xyz` can depend on the previous (updated) value of `xyz`. It'd be much better to test on valid data that does not produce `TRUE` for everything as you show here. If any of the values should be false and are incorrect here, please demonstrate what they should be; if all here as truly supposed to be true, then I suggest it would be better to show clear conditions where a false is justified.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, I have updated the question and added the expected outcome column ```expected_xyz```.

Comment: What you really want, it is not clear to me. It seems you want to update lower and upper by reference and not xyz per se. Also note that you never reach this scenario `upper = ifelse(xyz == FALSE &`, simply beause you default xyz on TRUE so the scenario where your value lays between lower and upper and xyz is FALSE cannot occur.

Comment: The scenario you have mentioned will not happen when the values of ```upper``` and ```lower``` are updated at runtime. This is the reason, I have posted this question. As mentioned by @r2evans, the best solution is to use ```Reduce```, but using it in this scenario is a little too complex.

Comment: I think there is no way to do this in base R or "simple" `data.table`, either with `Reduce` or `Map`; this is because it appears that you are optionally updating `lower`, `upper`, and `xyz` based on the initial results of `xyz` and the values from the previous row. (If it were just a single value updating, it might be feasible with `Map`/`mapply`. If you have a working `for` loop, I suggest you stick with it. If it does not work, post what you have and what isn't working about it.

Comment: FYI, the first argument to `Reduce` needs to be a function that accepts (at least) two arguments.

Comment: I do have a working ```for``` loop, however, it is painfully slow.

Comment: It would help, if you show you `for` loop. There is a common misunderstanding in `R` that `for` loops are slow, while `data.table` folks even recommend using `for` for certain problems.

Comment: I also don't understand, do you want to update `lower`, `upper`, and `xyz` in each row based on that row and the row before it? Or only `lower`?

Comment: @Alexis - I want to update ```lower```, ```upper```, and ```xyz``` in each row based on that row and the row before it. Please refer the ```Update-1``` in question

Comment: @Ben373 - I have added the ```for``` loop in the ```Update-3```. Also, I have shared the benchmarking results. Any suggestions to improve the efficiency of function with ```for``` loop are welcome.

Comment: In the for loop, the fist two cases are base on the value of the current row, and the upper and lower of the previous row, but in the data.table attempt, the two first cases are based only on the current row ..

Comment: @Smith - Yes, that's true. I don't know how to reference the previous values of ```upper``` and ```lower``` in ```data.table``` case. I have mentioned this in the benchmarking section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how you could do this with `data.table` even if you use `Reduce` because you want to modify more than 1 value iteratively.
In case it may convince you to try something else,
here's a C++ version with `Rcpp`.

Save this in `foo.cpp`:

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP foo_cpp(DataFrame df) {
    NumericVector value = df["value"];
    NumericVector lower = df["lower"];
    NumericVector upper = df["upper"];
    LogicalVector xyz = df["xyz"];

    for (auto current = 2; current < df.nrow(); current++) {
        auto previous = current - 1;

        if (value[current] > upper[previous]) {
            xyz[current] = true;
        } else if (value[current] < lower[previous]) {
            xyz[current] = false;
        } else {
            xyz[current] = xyz[previous];

            if (xyz[current] && lower[current] < lower[previous]) {
                lower[current] = lower[previous];
            }

            if (!xyz[current] && upper[current] > upper[previous]) {
                upper[current] = upper[previous];
            }
        }
    }

    return R_NilValue;
}
```

and in R:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("foo.cpp")
foo_cpp(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Alexis! This is indeed the fastest solution. No other solution comes even close to this. I have updated the benchmark results. Just one query, is there a reason you returned ```R_NilValue``` instead of ```df```?

Comment: @Saurabh just because `df` is modified in place, so the `NULL` return value can help indicate that.

Answer (score 1):

May be a recursive function could help - but it's not very efficient.

```
myFun <- function(tbl, n){
  if (n==1){
    tbl[n, xyz := TRUE]
  }else{
    tbl <- myFun(tbl, n-1)
    prev_upper <- tbl[n-1, upper]
    prev_lower <- tbl[n-1, lower]
    prev_xyz<- tbl[n-1, xyz]
    tbl[n, xyz := fcase(value > prev_upper, TRUE, 
                        value < prev_lower, FALSE,
                        value <= prev_upper & value >= prev_lower, prev_xyz)]
    tbl[n, lower := fcase(value <= prev_upper & value >= prev_lower
                          & lower< prev_lower
                          & xyz == TRUE, prev_lower,
                        rep_len(TRUE, length(lower)), lower)]
    tbl[n, upper := fcase(value <= prev_upper & value >= prev_lower
                          & xyz == FALSE
                          & upper > prev_upper, prev_upper,
                          rep_len(TRUE, length(upper)), upper)]
    print(n)
    
  }
  return(tbl)
}

res <- myFun(data, nrow(data) )
```

Comment: It's a great try @Mr. Smith. I really appreciate your effort. I haven't got a chance to dig deeper to understand the reason this recursiveness made this function slow but logic looks fine to me and results are also correct.